# EF Core 2.1. Add custom column to MigrationHistory table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

I use EF Core 2.1 Code-First.

`SELECT * FROM [dbo].[__MigrationsHistory]` returns table from 2 columns

- MigrationId
- ProductVersion

I am looking for a way to add one more column `AppliedOn` which will store the time when migration was really applied to database.

Comment: You could have a naming convention in your Migration Classes that indicate the version, in which case you dont need to modify the standard migrations, might be easier going forward?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do that in SQL :

```
alter table [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] add AppliedOn Datetime default getdate()
```

When EF applies a migration to the database it inserts a row in the table `__MigrationHistory`. This SQL Script adds the column `AppliedOn` with a default value at `getDate()`. When a row is inserted the column will contain the current datetime of this insert.

Or, you could do the same thing with an EF Migration :

By adding to the first migration(or to a new migration):

```
public partial class Intial : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "AppliedOnUtc",
            schema: "Conversations",
            table: "__MigrationsHistory",                
            defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()"
        );
    }
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an article from Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456841(v=vs.113).aspx) that indicates how to do this in a slightly more EF friendly fashion although they suggest a lot of caution as you could inadvertently break migrations.

This article only supports EF6.0 onwards which *may* be supported by EF Core 2.1 but I've not tried so I don't know whether it is available to you and the article is unclear on that.

I totally get why you want to do it, but you could consider a custom patch table instead and insert into it from a Configuration.cs class when you create your code first migration. Yes it's another step, yes it's not as elegant, but it might be safer from an EF standpoint.